# How to add buttonlocation in a for loop?

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to put some buttons on random locations in Windows Form like this:

```
for (int i = 0; < shuffle.Length; i++)
{
    //This line doesn't work
    Controls["button" + (i + 1).ToString()].Location = new Point(shuffle[i], 250);

    //But this line is OK
    Controls["button" + (i + 1).ToString()].Text = text[i];
}
```

When I write the next lines is works fine but how to put that in a loop and change 1,2,and 3 to (i +1)?

```
button1.Location = new Point(shuffle[0], 250);
button2.Location = new Point(shuffle[1], 250);
button3.Location = new Point(shuffle[2], 250);
```

Comment: We need to see what exception you are encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop on the buttons instead of the numbers, like:

```
var buttons = new List<Button>(){button1, button2, button3};
i = 0;
foreach (var button in buttons)
{
    button.Location = new Point(shuffle[i], 250);
    button.Text = text[i];
    i++;
    }
```

Then you can add all the button to the list and cycle thru them.